# Unable to insert data into existing BigQuery Table?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, insert, google-bigquery, try-catch

I am trying to insert some data into bigquery table which is already exists. But I am unable to get that data into the table.

I tried standard example provided by google (insert_rows) but no luck. I have also referred this:https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5539
I have tried passing this data as list of tupples as well but same issue with that too.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import datetime
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('my_dataset_id')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('my_destination_table_id')
table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
rows_to_insert = [
    {u'jobName': 'writetobigquery'},
    {u'startDatetime': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')},
    {u'jobStatus': 'Success'},
    {u'logMessage': 'NA'},
]
errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)
```

When I execute this, I don't get an error, but its not writing anything into table. It will be really great if anyone suggested something that would work for me. Thank You!

Comment: I run the snippet you provided and it works fine for me. The only thing is that it inserts 4 different rows with only one value in each one. Is your table already created with the proper schema? Did you query the table and it didn't return any results?

Comment: Python 2.7? Is it a new dev or an update ?

Comment: @itroulli The table is already created with the proper schema, After running above snippet I am querying the table but it didn't return any data as result.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes I am using python 2.7 (Update)

Comment: Are you performing a query for finding the data? Or do you use the free preview?

Comment: I tried with all fields being STRING type. If I try with startDatetime being DATETIME type, I get an error of incorrect format: 'Invalid datetime string "2019-08-27-092247"'. According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type) the valid format for DATETIME is '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'. If I change '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S' from your code to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', it works fine. I can post my modified code as an answer if you want.

Comment: @ Yes, please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some modifications on your code I could make it work as expected. I changed your row from being a list of dictionaries of one value each to be a dictionary with all the columns in one row. I also changed the datetime format as it was invalid for BigQuery (valid format can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type)). So the following snippet should work fine:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import datetime

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('my_dataset_id')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('my_destination_table_id')
table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
rows_to_insert = [
    {u'jobName': 'writetobigquery',
    u'startDatetime': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    u'jobStatus': 'Success',
    u'logMessage': 'NA'}
]
errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)
print "Errors occurred:", errors
```

Comment: @KaustubhGhole Could you please accept (and maybe upvote) my answer as the correct one since it worked for you?

Comment: I did it but since I am new to stackoverflow and have reputations less than 15, though its recorded but not displayed publicly.
Here is the message from stackoverflow:  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @KaustubhGhole No worries for the upvote but you can sure approve it even if you are new. There should be a green check sign next to my answer that you can click on.  Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your rows be a list of dictionaries? I assume your table schema is like `jobName, startDatetime, jobStatus, logMessage`, then:

```
rows_to_insert = [
    {
      u'jobName': 'writetobigquery',
      u'startDatetime': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S'),
      u'jobStatus': 'Success',
      u'logMessage': 'NA'
    }
]
errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)
```

Comment: @ khan I tried with your approach but it didn't return anything. The query (SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset_id.table_id`) result is: "This query returned no results."